# Velocity in WF4

Tags: caching, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

If I use Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Client and Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core assembly I get exception:
*The type or namespace name 'ApplicationServer' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    .....\CacheUtil.cs*

And I get Warning: 
*The referenced assembly "Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.    WFReport*

This occurs in a separate assembly with WF4. And I want run it from a separate assembly Asp.net web forms.I wont that everyone workflow would use common cache.(VS2010 .net 4.0)

What's wrong? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WF4 assembly, in properties change Target framework:  .NET Framework 4 Client Profile => .NET Framework 4.